# No logs in Android 8.0.0 TV emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-tv

I am not getting any error logs in my **Android TV (8.0.0)** emulator. Although It works fine on the **Android TV (7.1.1)** emulator. I wonder what is the reason for this?

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you have? I am able to see the error logs for the 8.0 TV emulator. I am running beta7 version of Studio. Also, sometimes I forget to clear my filter and it looks like logs do not show up...

Comment: I am running 2.3.3. I guess it has to do with emulator. I am not getting logs in the Android 8.0.0 phone emulator as well

Comment: All other logs are showing up properly, If I write `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Hello");`. It will work but if I replace it with Log.e(...) then it'll not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! I had some issues with the Oreo image been used in the emulator. I just deleted the emulator/s and again downloaded it and voila!